# 2012: Is Burrrn still the best freeware Audio CD burning software for Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, compact-disc, burning, cd-burning

It's been ages since [Burrrn](http://www.burrrn.net) has been updated - 2006 was the date of last revision, and I wonder if there's anything now to supplant it as the recommended freeware windows burner.

Personally I've had such problems with Burrrn, that it's not worth even trying it anymore. It seems every second time I use Burrrn, there's some error (or group of errors) that makes it just not burn. Sometimes I tick 'raw' driver option and it then works, but then some other error happens at other times.

And over the years, I've gotten into the habit of just using Windows Media Player as my burner, it's reliable and 'just works'. But today I tried it and some irritating 'burn rights' message came up preventing me from burning WAV files taken from my own purchased CDs, so I need some other program to be reliable for me from now on.

So what's the state of things, in 2012? Might [EAC](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/) be the one?

Thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This [nice comparison site](http://alternativeto.net/software/burrrn/) reveals that [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/en/home) is by far more popular. This is also my choice. For ripping I used EAC but for burning CDBurnerXP.